# Firefox Update to v85.0

Tags: 20.04, firefox, chromium, google

Problem with graphics in Google Sheets after update today to v85.0

[image]

This is only happening with Google Sheets in FF and no other site seems to have the same issue.

What I have done so far:

I have opened Google Sheets in Chromium. No problem encountered.

I have opened Google Sheets on another Ubuntu 20.04 LTS PC no problem encountered.

Analysis:

The only difference between the two 20.04 PC's is that the one with the problem shown uses an HDMI connection for screen display. The other uses SVGA.

[image]

Bizarre that this is only occurs in Google Sheets though and would be grateful for any pointers at a fix.

I have rebooted the machine and the issue with Google Sheets persists but Google Calendar presents no problem at all - the screen is rendered correctly.

UPDATE from Mozilla

[image]

It appears this is not so much a bug but a conflict between Ubuntu/Firefox and HDMI graphics settings for which there is a suggested change to Firefox parameters to enable correct rendering and overcome the issue.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Firefox specifically and needs to be handled as a bug report upstream with Firefox, which you indicate you've filed.  Until there's a resolution fro Firefox and Mozilla, there's not really much we can do to fix this or address it downstream here in Ubuntu.